Convert a character string "d.m.Y" into a date in format "Y-m-d"
Currently, I have imported data into R with fread and the import works perfectly. However, for 2 columns the date is read in as "d.m.Y" and saved as a character. The problem is that the columns should be in date format and in the following format "Y-m-d". I just can't get these columns to be adjusted accordingly...
# Function for standardizing the date format
standardize_date_format <- function(df) {
  date_columns <- c("Column1", "Column2")
  for (col in date_columns) {
    if (col %in% names(df)) {
      df[[col]] <- parse_date_time(df[[col]], orders = c("dmy", "mdy", "ymd"))
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

# Standardize the date format in the data frame
data.frame <- standardize_date_format(old)

Applying dput(head(old) I receive the following output (limited to the necessary data due to sensitive information:
Wrong format col1 and col2
Column1 =` c("01.01.2024", "01.01.2024", 
"01.01.2024", "01.01.2024", "01.01.2024", "01.01.2024")
Column2 = c("0001-01-01", 
"0001-01-01", "0001-01-01", "0001-01-01", "0001-01-01", "0001-01-01"
)
Correct format:
TIMESTAMP = structure(c(1711012856, 
    1711012856, 1711012856, 1711012856, 1711012856
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")


Try as.Date("23.4.2024", format = "%d.%m.%Y")   which gives "2024-04-23".

Note that in R the format of a date (how it is displayed) is separate from how it is stored, so what matters is that the result is stored as a date, not as a string.  for example, today's date in my comment above is actually just stored as 19836 - try unclass() on the date to see this.

I have adapted the code according to your suggestion. But unfortunately both columns are still in character format... even if no error message appears, which I have included...

Function for standardizing the date format
standardize_date_format <- function(df) {
  date_columns <- c("Column1", "Column2")
  for (col in date_columns) {
    if (col %in% names(df)) {
      df[[col]] <- tryCatch(
        as.Date(df[[col]], format = "%d.%m.%Y"), 
        error = function(e) {
          warning(paste("Error when converting the column:", col))
          NA
        }
      )
    }
  }
  return(df)
}


Could you please add a small reproducible sample from your actual dataset to your question?  Output of dput(head(old)) would be ideal.

Unfortunately I cant post the whole output due to sensitive data. However I can provide the output for the both columns which are in the wrong format and also for one column, where the format is correct.
Wrong format col1 and col2
Column1 =` c("01.01.2024", "01.01.2024",
"01.01.2024", "01.01.2024", "01.01.2024", "01.01.2024")
Column2 = c("0001-01-01",
"0001-01-01", "0001-01-01", "0001-01-01", "0001-01-01", "0001-01-01"
)
Correct format:
TIMESTAMP = structure(c(1711012856,
1711012856, 1711012856, 1711012856, 1711012856
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

How sensitive is a vector of dates stored in character format? If you have non-date-like data (eg. name or address), then you can't expect R to convert these to valid dates.

Try this:
# Toy data
my_df <- structure(
  list(
    some_id = c(4785L, 1502L, 4429L, 4695L, 5089L,  8885L, 4051L, 9191L), 
    
    col_date_1 = c(
      "16.04.2024", "17.04.2024", "18.04.2024", "19.04.2024", 
      "20.04.2024", "21.04.2024", "22.04.2024", "23.04.2024"), 
    
    col_date_2 = c(
      "16.04.2024", "17.04.2024", "18.04.2024", "19.04.2024", 
      "20.04.2024", "21.04.2024", "22.04.2024", "23.04.2024")),
  
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

# Columns to parse
my_cols <- c("col_date_1", "col_date_2")

# Parsing dates with lubridate::dmy()
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# ----------------
my_df <- mutate(my_df, across(any_of(my_cols), \(x) lubridate::dmy(x)))

The output:
> my_df
  some_id col_date_1 col_date_2
1    4785 2024-04-16 2024-04-16
2    1502 2024-04-17 2024-04-17
3    4429 2024-04-18 2024-04-18
4    4695 2024-04-19 2024-04-19
5    5089 2024-04-20 2024-04-20
6    8885 2024-04-21 2024-04-21
7    4051 2024-04-22 2024-04-22
8    9191 2024-04-23 2024-04-23

> str(my_df)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ some_id   : int  4785 1502 4429 4695 5089 8885 4051 9191
 $ col_date_1: Date, format: "2024-04-16" "2024-04-17" "2024-04-18" "2024-04-19" ...
 $ col_date_2: Date, format: "2024-04-16" "2024-04-17" "2024-04-18" "2024-04-19" ...


I tried it with your approach but it unfortunately also did not help :/
Function to standardize date formats
standardize_date_format <- function(df) {
Define the columns to be converted to Date format
date_columns <- c("Column1", "Column2")
Use mutate() and across() to convert specified columns to Date
df <- df %>%
mutate(across(any_of(date_columns), ~ dmy(.)))
return(df)
}

@TK I'm looking at your data sample now and will try to edit the response accordingly!

@TK your data is just the same "line" repeated six times (Column1 = "01.01.2024" and Column2 = "0001-01-01"). Column1 format is ok, but what kind of date do you expect from Column2? Days and months only, maybe?

@TK you can try to select just the two columns you need and take a sample.
If your df is called old, with library(tidyverse) you can
old %>% select(Column1, Column2) %>% slice_sample(n = 10) %>% dput().
If "Column.." isn't their real names, you can
old %>% select(date_col_1 = original_name_1, date_col_2 = original_name_2) %>% slice_sample(n = 10) %>% dput().
